# animate child elements of div

Tags: jquery

I am trying to animate images inside div#image1.I am having the following markUp.

```
 <div id="images"> 
     <img src="Images/Blue%20hills.jpg" width="100px" height="100px" />
     <img src="Images/Sunset.jpg" width="100px" height="100px" style="display:none;"/>
     <img src="Images/Sunset.jpg" width="100px" height="100px" style="display:none;"/>
     <img src="Images/Winter.jpg"width="100px" height="100px" style="display:none;"/>
 </div>
 <ol id="paging">
     <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">1</a></li>
     <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">2</a></li>
     <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">3</a></li>
     <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">4</a></li>
 </ol>
```

and i am trying to animate by

```
  $('#paging ol li a').bind('click', function() {
            var text = $(this).text();

            $('#images img').get(text).animate({ width: '200px', height: '200px', opacity: 0 });
```

But it is throwing exception

```
$("#images img").get(parseInt(text) - 1).animate is not a function
        });
```

How should i do this.
Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the ol ID and OL in the jQuery selector.
Use only one i.e ol or #paging and use nth-child selector
Change it to

```
$('#paging li a').bind('click', function() {
  var text = $(this).text();
  $('#images img:nth-child(' + text + ')' ).animate({ width: '200px', height: '200px', opacity: 0 });
});
```

Comment: Good catch on the `ol` selector. I missed that.

Comment: ...Although the selector must be correct in the actual code, otherwise OP wouldn't get the exception.

Comment: Thats a valid point...Maybe the html that is posted are wrapped in an element with the id #paging

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) instead of [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) so that it gives you a jQuery object instead of a DOM element.

```
$('#images img').eq(text).animate({ width: '200px', height: '200px', opacity: 0 });
```

If this is going to happen more than once or twice, you may want to consider caching the images.

Outside the handler:

```
var imgs = $('#images img');
```

Then inside the handler:

```
imgs.eq(text).animate({...
```